# Creating Efficient Oracle/PL_SQL Query Help

Tags: database, oracle

Hope you are having a great day. 
I came across a problem.

In database the use of distinct is not efficient and it poses numerous timeout problems.

So In a simple case I have...

```
select distinct first_value(e.error_message) over (order by create_date desc)
                  from database e
```

Which exactly one result which error message is ordered by latest and it is the first value of its kind, now when I run it it takes about .8 seconds which isn't bad, but the problem is, joining and making this query bigger and doing more than just retrieving errors will be a problem.

So if I do the following query...

```
select  first_value(e.error_message) over (order by create_date desc)
                  from database e
```

this query takes about .4 seconds, but the problem is only want the first item that is given. How do I do this, I do not know the row number that is specific with it.

Thanks everyone.

****EDIT***

Just to let everyone know, using Rob's solution has made my huge query more efficient TRY NOT TO USE DISTINCT WHEN POSSIBLE!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select max(e.error_message) keep (dense_rank last order by create_date)
  from database e
```

EDIT: Here is the link to the documentation of the [LAST function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions083.htm#sthref1206)

It select the last error message when sorted by create_date.

Comment: works even better, can you explain this, I'm fairly new to writing queries thanks. I havent used keep or dense rank yet either

Comment: I've added a link to the documentation and an explanation.

Comment: It's explained in the link. It's all part of the syntax of the aggregate function LAST.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the select:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        select first_value(e.error_message) over (order by create_date desc)               from database e 
       )
 WHERE rownum < 2;
```

OR

```
SELECT UNIQUE 
       val
  FROM (
        select first_value(e.error_message) over (order by create_date desc) as val
          from database e 
       );
```

Comment: Ahhh,I didn't think about the first one. the first one only takes about .2-.3 seconds but the next one takes about .8 because i believe of the UNIQUE function, it cycles through the result and checks to see if its unique. Thanks a bunch the answer is amazing.

Comment: This is a good answer, but using a regular `order by` clause may be more efficient that using an analytic function: `SELECT * FROM (select e.error_message from database e order by create_date desc) WHERE rownum = 1;`.

Comment: @Allan Allan, you are correct, maybe we over think it sometimes, but in the end a simple select query is in fact faster than the analytic function. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to do this without wrapping it in a select out of curiosity, because I believe sql has a first function of some sort